# PHP time() not honest

Tags: php, datetime

im using this function

time()
in php im doing

> echo date("c",time());

however its not returning me the honest time , as i can see my system time is 12:20 but the output is

> 2012-08-24T08:48:42+02:00

what seems to be the problem , i tried doing :

> echo date("r",time());

but same results were observed

*Just for people who might reffer the question latter : you dont need to set any time zones , you just need to change the php.ini file on your localhost
you have a field "date.timezone" you must set it to the same time zone as your OS thats it*

Comment: Is the script executed on your computer or a remote server? If its on a remote server it will use the server time.

Comment: my localhost , on this very machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to set the timezone first. I guess that would be the problem. Check [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). To check your current timezone, use [date_default_timezone_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). As of PHP5.4, if you don't set anything, PHP defaults to use UTC. (Check the manual pages).

Comment: for the system time ? wouldnt php just pick up the time from the system whatever time zone its in

Comment: No, you will have to explicitly set the timezone. For what you know, your hosting server could be in, say, the US, but your target audience might be in Africa.

Comment: no no no im trying to just run this on my localhost , on XAMPP , i dont want to host it anywhere else

Comment: Still you will have to set the timezone.